# Arduino - Return String

Tags: arduino

I am trying to return a string.

```
String getBinary(String str) {

  String message = str;
  message.toLowerCase();
  int length = message.length();
  String binaryNumber = "";

  for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {

    char c = message.charAt(i);
    int letter = ;
    Serial.println(letter);

    binaryNumber = binaryNumber + String(c, BIN) + " ";

  }

  return binaryNumber;

}
```

But I get this error:

```
binary_telegraph.cpp: In function ‘String getBinary(String)’:
binary_telegraph.cpp:53:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which line is line 53?

Comment: 53 : } That's the end of the for loop

Comment: Where is the electrical engineering problem?

Comment: @user1978786  FYI. Check out the [proposed specialized Arduino board on SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino). I bet, they would benefit from your participation.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
   int letter = ;
```

Is a syntax error.  You can have either

```
   int letter;
```

or

```
   int letter = 1;  // need some number here
```

Comment: Oops! Sorry for the stupid question. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Angelatlarge, don't make all your answers community wikis! You won't earn reputation for them.

Comment: For reference: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2818/17592. Interesting.